# Proving the solution of a repeated root differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you only have to plug the proposed solution into the equation and check that it works. Maybe you are interested in the way to find the general solution.

Writing $Y = (x,y)$ and applying the matrix multiplication, you will find $$x' = 6x -9y$$ and $$y'=x.$$ Deriving the first equality, you get $$x''-6x'+9x =0.$$ The characteristic polynomial is $z^2-6z+9 =(z-3)^2$. Hence the general solution of your equation is $$x(t) = (At+B)e^{3t},$$ where $A$ and $B$ are determined by the initial conditions. (After that, $y$ is also determined, using $x' = 6x -9y$.)

Now, your particular solution is gived by $A=3$ and $B=1$.